# Products Table Joining Inventory

Tags: php, mysql

I'm having trouble coming up the SQL query to join and get a count of my inventory table.

I've got a products table that has no association with the inventory table. The inventory table has a foreign key to the products table called 'product_id'. There can be multiple rows in the inventory table for the product. I want to get all products with a count of the inventory records for that product. If there are no inventory records for that product it should show 0.

Answer (score 0):

Seems to me that you only need a simple (left) join and group by. Something like

```
select p.product_id, count(p.product_id)
from products p
left join inventory i on p.product_id = i.product_id
group by p.product_id;
```

Would have been better to have a more precise schema and what you had already tried to get to your result though.

Note: I assumed your column was called `product_id` in your `products` table as well, if it was simple `id`, replace `p.product_id` by `p.id`, of course.

Answer (score 0):

Thank you turns out it was my GROUP BY that was throwing me off. I was grouping by inventory.product_id instead of by product.id so I was only getting back entries from the matched inventory table.